# What is the best time complexity of checking the inequality $a_1x_1 + \cdots + a_mx_m \le K$ to have a non-negative integer solution?

Tags: inequality, logic, proof-verification, computational-complexity, integers

Consider $$a_1x_1 + \cdots + a_mx_m \le K$$

with $a_1, a_2, \ldots , a_m$ and $K$ being integers.

> I only need to know if the inequality has an integer solution or not.

It means that there is no need to find all the (probable available) solutions.

Actually, I need to know the best possible approach to address this problem according to its time complexity.

Comment: There is a big literature on decision procedures of this kind. To give you a start on your literature search, it seems that you are looking for an algorithm that exhibits best possible worst-case time-complexity for purely existential formulas in Presburger arithmetic. (I would be surprised if there is a known lower bound on this complexity problem, but that is just a guess.)  If none of that makes sense, then you need to start with a textbook reference like Harrison's *Handbook of Practical Logic and Automated Reasoning* or   Kroening and Strichman's book *Decision Procedures*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Under the condition that every $x_k$ is non-negative,
if $K \geq 0$ then set $x_1 = \cdots = x_m = 0.$
Then $a_1x_1 + \cdots + a_mx_m = 0 \leq K$.

If $K < 0$ and one of the coefficients $a_k$ is negative, set
$x_k \geq \frac{K}{a_k}$ (so that $a_kx_k \leq K$) and set all other $x_i=0$.

If $K < 0$ and $a_k \geq 0$ for every $k$, then there is no solution, since
necessarily $a_1x_1 + \cdots + a_mx_m \geq 0 > K.$

So the best case is one step to determine that $K \geq 0$.
The worst case is $m+1$ steps: one step to determine that $K < 0$,
$m-1$ steps to determine that $m-1$ of the coefficients $a_k$ are all
non-negative, and one more step to determine whether the remaining
coefficient is negative.

Comment: Thanks David! it was helpful. Now, if I want to find out whether the following system has a solution or not, what your suggestion is. 
(1) $x_1+x_2+\hdots +x_m=d$
(2) $0\leq x_i\leq u_i$, for $i=1,\ 2,\hdots, m$
(3) $a_1x_1+\hdots +a_mx_m\leq K$

We know that $d$ and $K$ and all the $a_i$s are positive integer numbers. For sure, $u_i$s are positive integer number as well.

Comment: If the $x_i$ did not have to be integers, (1) and (2) would describe a polygon with vertices on the edges of the $m$-dimensional rectangular "box" described by (2). You could try (3) at each vertex of that polygon. But I think maybe you can find the minimum value of the left side of (3) quicker by rearranging the terms so that $a_i\leq a_{i+1}$ for $i=1, \ldots,m-1$, and then setting $x_i=u_i$ for $i=1,\ldots,k$, $x_{k+1}=d-(x_1+\cdots+x_k)$, and $x_{k+2}=\cdots=x_m=0$ for the largest possible $k$ such that (1) holds.

Comment: Thank you so much.... very nice and efficient approach and really simple as well!!! That was a big help!